# I'm using vueJS 2.6.10, my component emit an undefined value

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, emit

i'am using Vue.js 2.0 and, i'm trying to emit an event from child component to parent component.

The event is well executed on the parent component, but the passed value is undefined?

You can see my code below:

**child component:**

```
<template>
<div class="input-file-container" :class="classDiv">
  <input :id="'upload-file-'+item.id" :name="item.id" type="file" v-on:change="handleImageUpload" />
</div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    @Component
    export default class InputFileComponent extends Vue {
        public image:string = '';
        @Prop() public item?: PieceIdentite;

        public handleImageUpload (e:Event) {
            /* ... */
            imageCompression(file, options).then( (compressedFile:Blob) => {
                /* ... */
                myService.myFuction(formData).then( response =>{
                    vm.$emit('input', {
                        'formData': formData,
                        checkFile : response
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

**parent component:**

```
    <template>
      <div class="input-file-container" >
            <InputFileComponent :item="item" @input="inputFileValue(input)" ></InputFileComponent>
      </div>
    </template>
<script lang="ts">
    /* ... */
    @Component({
        components: {
            InputFileComponent
        },
    })
    export default class PieceIdentite extends Vue {
        public checkImage:any;
        public inputFileValue(input:any){
            this.checkImage = input ;
            console.log('input::', this.checkImage);
        }
    }
</script>
```

when the "handleImageUpload" event is called, the "inputFileValue" function is well executed, but the input value is worth undefined
Can anybody help me?

Comment: @input="inputFileValue($event)"

Comment: @input="inputFileValue"